# Veracrypt - Unable to decrypt disk at boot time after RAM change

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, encryption, veracrypt

Since the laptop is encrypted with Veracrypt (1.25.9), after a RAM change the laptop no longer recognizes veracrypt boot. ( how is this possible? lol )
That is, I enter the correct password and simply start the Windows 11 disk recovery.
After some insistence I gave up the idea of ​​trying to boot with the laptop itself.
I experimented by putting the nvme disk on another computer as external disk to use a portable version of veracrypt to try to decrypt the disk in another way.
Veracrypt informs me that the password is incorrect (I checked the password several times and special characters).
I can't recover the disk in any way and I really need to recover the disk, urgently.
I've also tried some ways to recover, but it's certainly not worth it because the disk is encrypted.
I used paid software, Disk Drill, Mini Tool Partition Recovery but as the partition is RAW, I can't do much.

Brand: Dell
Model: Precision 3570
Operating System: Windows 11x64 in Portuguese.

Comment: Can't you return the old RAM?

Comment: Hey harrymc, all the procedures at the hardware level have already been tested, I put the old memory in, I tested it with two memory sticks, only one, i tested in another laptop, same model and i did try several things.

Comment: If you have a previous disk image, made before RAM change, you might try restoring a disk to that version and decrypting it.

Comment: Honestly, and disagreeing with the previous commenters, if *"Veracrypt informs (...) that the password is incorrect"* then it very likely is wrong, regardless of how certain you are of it being correct.

Comment: DrMoishe Pippik, I don't have a disk image, nor any disk backup. It's really complicated.

Comment: ChanganAuto, I'm sure the password is correct. Because when I enter the veracrypt password at boot it accepts it, but goes into disk recovery mode.
I think one of the disk partitions is corrupted!