# Is it safe to switch RAM (two old for two new) when using VeraCrypt?

Tags: memory, encryption, veracrypt

I use VeraCrypt to encrypt my C: drive. I purchased new RAM (2-kit) and plan to replace the old ones (2-kit).

I read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1756999/veracrypt-unable-to-decrypt-disk-at-boot-time-after-ram-change?newreg=66a6b8c81ae04d66a81a89535cb88664) about a problem when replacing RAM and using VeraCrypt, so I wanted to confirm:

**Is replacing RAM+Veracrypt combination safe? Are there any precautions I should take?**

Comment: The question you linked is just an uninformed misrepresentation or misunderstanding of "something" that happened - file system corruption - unrelated to RAM, even a faulty one, but likely related with what that person did and didn't disclose in the question itself. In summary, that was a textbook example of the *post hoc ergo propter hoc* fallacy.

Comment: I don't know why you think RAM is related to VeraCrypt (disk encryption). That question doesn't have anything that suggests the issue is caused by changing RAM. Unless you damage other hardware while changing RAM, nothing will happen to your encrypted disk.

Comment: That said, if you're soooo afraid, then disconnect the drive before booting the computer with the new RAM. You can then boot some diagnostic tools to test the new memory and if everything is OK youi can use the computer as always.

Comment: @Destroy666 As I mention in the question, I am not sure how VeraCrypt works, which is why I'm asking before I break something. I like the answer's explanation plus the suggestion to make a disk image to stay safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that Veracrypt is completely portable -- not only to another PC, but even to different operating systems on different machines. A Veracrypt -encrypted file made on a Windows PC or a  [Mac](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/55445/veracrypt) could be opened and modified on a PC running [Linux Mint](https://linuxhint.com/install-veracrypt-linux-mint/) or even a [Raspberry Pi](https://linuxhint.com/install-use-veracrypt-raspberry-pi/). Unlike Bitlocker, it does not check hardware, which can cause issues, e.g., if a [motherboard is replaced](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131541/bitlocker-prompting-for-recovery-key-after-motherboard-replacement). Logically, any change you make to your PC should have no effect on being able to decrypt the disk.

That said, many questions have been asked at this site about what can be done to recover when there are issues with whole-disk encryption, with the sad answer, for most, being, "nothing." If you use full-disk encryption, or even just the C: partition, make frequent full disk images **and verify that the image can be restored and unencrypted.** A company at which I worked made daily backups... and on the day one was need to restore a vital project, *all* of the backups were found to be defective.